# "ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted" during Python connection to Hive in Dataproc

Tags: hive, token, pyodbc, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using Python to connect to Hive on GCP Dataproc from a Mac laptop behind VPN. I'm using several client packages including `pyhive`, `pyodbc`, `impyla`. They have all encountered the following issue shown in server log. I'm not sure in what situation this happens. It does not always happen.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
{
  "insertId": "yo09j6v27lip3l6yj",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "filename": "yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-test-sql-hive-debug-m.log",
    "class": "org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager",
    "message": "ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_dataproc_cluster",
    "labels": {
      "cluster_uuid": "xxx-9a09-475e-9c2b-36fa13885367",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "xxx",
      "cluster_name": "test-sql-hive-debug"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-03-13T09:41:00.051Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "compute.googleapis.com/zone": "us-central1-a",
    "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "test-sql-hive-debug-m",
    "compute.googleapis.com/resource_id": "xxx"
  },
  "logName": "projects/wmt-catalog-ds-classy/logs/yarn-yarn-resourcemanager",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-03-13T09:41:00.263824982Z"
}
```